# Magento getCollection function returning db info not data

Tags: magento-1.9, database, orders

i want to get all orders from Magento but its returning the db info not the data

```
class Host_Autox_OrderController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction(){  
        $ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($ordersCollection->getData());
    }


}
```

And here is the output

```
object(Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Collection)#70 (34) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(22) "sales_order_collection" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(16) "order_collection" ["_model":protected]=> string(11) "sales/order" ["_resourceModel":protected]=> string(11) "sales/order" ["_resource":protected]=> object(Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order)#102 (21) { ["_eventPrefix":protected]=> string(20) "sales_order_resource" ["_eventObject":protected]=> string(8) "resource" ["_grid":protected]=> bool(true) ["_useIncrementId":protected]=> bool(true) ["_entityCodeForIncrementId":protected]=> string(5) "order" ["_useIsObjectNew":protected]=> bool(true) ["_entityTypeForIncrementId":protected]=> string(0) "" ["_virtualGridColumns":protected]=> NULL ["_gridColumns":protected]=> NULL ["_resources":protected]=> object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource)#83 (5) { ["_connectionTypes":protected]=> array(0) { } ["_connections":protected]=> array(69) { ["core_setup"]=> object(Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql)#38 (31) { ["_defaultStmtClass":protected]=> string(29) "Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql"
```

Something like that

**Update**

is there any limit to getData because its only fetching approx 1200 records after that it shows the blank page. Getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Unknown: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: How do you output the result ? What code do you use?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism var_dump($order ); also tried foreach

Answer (score 0):

```
$ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
echo "<pre>"; print_r($ordersCollection->getData());
```

Comment: Now page is blank, not printing anything.

Comment: try uncommenting this line (#ini_set('display_errors', 1);) from the index.php present at root dir and check for any error present.

Comment: that's already uncommented.

Comment: show ur code please

Comment: i  updated my original post please check.

Comment: since u said page is blank. please check wheather ur code is coming in the controller or not

Comment: yes, its coming to this controller.

Comment: is there any limit to getData because its only fetching approx 1200 records after that it shows the blank page.

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
  $ordersCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection();
         echo "<pre>";
  foreach($ordersCollection as $order){
     print_r($order->getData());
  }
```

Comment: is there any limit to getData because its only fetching approx 1200 records after that it shows the blank page.

Comment: May be `max_execution_time` error increase `max_execution_time` from php.ini for that